# How to set value of span within an Ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using an ng-repeat in order to list the contents of my data model where the content is being displayed correctly. However, as I am creating a contacts application, I am utilising a circle shape with text inside of it to display the first character from the first name and the first character from the last name, of each contact in the list - my code for this can be seen below:

HTML:

```
<ul class="collection" ng-show="customers.length">
        <li class="collection-item avatar" ng-click="showUserDetail(customer.id)" ng-repeat="customer in customers | orderBy: 'first_name' | filter: searchText" ng-class="{'active': customer.id == selectedUser.id}">
            <span ng-init="setContactCircle(customer.first_name,customer.last_name)" id="contact-info" class="contact-circle">TC</span>
            <span class="title">{{customer.first_name}}  {{customer.last_name}}</span>
            <p>{{customer.email}}
                <br> {{customer.mobile_number}}
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

JS:

```
$scope.setContactCircle = function(first_name,last_name) {  
    var strFirst = first_name.charAt(0);
    var strLast = last_name.charAt(0);
    var strName = strFirst + strLast;

    /* span = document.getElementById("contact-info");
    txt = document.createTextNode(strName);
    span.innerHTML = txt.textContent; */

    //document.getElementById("contact-info").innerHTML = strName;

    $("#contact-info").text(strName);
    console.log(strName);
}
```

The ng-init appears to be working as the first character from the first name and the first character from the last name are being outputted to the console in 'console.log(strName);' but the text is not being set on the span class.

**EDIT**

Thank you all for your help where the below has resolved the issue.

HTML:

```
<span ng-bind="setContactCircle(customer)" id="contact-info" class="contact-circle"></span>
```

JS:

```
$scope.setContactCircle = function(customer) {  
    var strFirst = customer.first_name.charAt(0);
    var strLast = customer.last_name.charAt(0);
    return strFirst + strLast;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing jquery and angular. Both are attempting to manipulate the DOM and they don't typically play nice together.

Could you please try -

```
<span ng-bind="setContactCircle(customer)" id="contact-info" class="contact-circle"></span>


$scope.setContactCircle = function(first_name,last_name) {  
    var strFirst = first_name.charAt(0);
    var strLast = last_name.charAt(0);
    return strFirst + strLast;
}
```

Comment: After making some slight changes (see edited answer) this worked - thank you! Was only using jquery as the other JS I was trying to use (which I commented out) did not seem to be working either but thank you for your help with resolving this.

Answer (score 3):

Manupulating DOM elements from your controller is a bad Angular design. Instead of using $("#contact-info").text you can user angular data binding.

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<ul class="collection" ng-show="customers.length">
    <li class="collection-item avatar" ng-click="showUserDetail(customer.id)" ng-repeat="customer in customers | orderBy: 'first_name' | filter: searchText" ng-class="{'active': customer.id == selectedUser.id}">
        <span ng-init="setContactCircle(customer)" id="contact-info" class="contact-circle">customer.circle</span>
        <span class="title">{{customer.first_name}}  {{customer.last_name}}</span>
        <p>{{customer.email}}
            <br> {{customer.mobile_number}}
        </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$scope.setContactCircle = function(customer) {  
  customer.circle = customer.first_name.charAt(0) + customer.last_name.charAt(0);
}
```